# account for fixed header with smooth scroll

Tags: jquery

I Have a jQuery script am using for some smooth scrolling on my site, and i have a fixed position header, but I'm not sure how to account for the fixed header size, as when it scrolls down, the fixed header covers a title.

```
$(function () {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function () {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you get the `header.height()` and subtract from the `target.offset().top`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to accomodate for the height of the fixed header by subtracting it from the position you are moving the view to.

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: target.offset().top - fixedHeader.outerHeight()
}, 1000);
```

Just replace "fixedHeader" with whatever element you are using for fixed header.

Answer (score 0):

Here is piece of HTML and CSS which is creating fixed header:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            background: #000;
        }

        .header-cont {
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
        }

        .header {
            height: 50px;
            background: #F0F0F0;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0px auto;
        }

        .content {
            width: 960px;
            background: #F0F0F0;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            height: 2000px;
            margin: 70px auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header-cont">
        <div></div>
    </div>

    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, sorry i should have explained a bit better, i have edited my original question