# HTML: href to div then minus the height of sticky navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigationbar

So, I am working on an website, and have sticky navigation bar.I want it so that whenever I click on my nav bar, it will go to the id then scroll back the height of the nav bar. is there anyway I could do this?

Comment: have you looked at using jquery already?

Comment: never done it before. Can you explain a bit more? I only know CSS and HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [account for fixed header with smooth scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119810/account-for-fixed-header-with-smooth-scroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HTML and CSS alone you can do it the following way:

At the very beginning of each section/DIV to which you want to link, create another DIV with an own ID, absolute position and a negative `top` setting that equals and compensates the height of the navbar. The `a` tags are linked to those elements. It's important that the parent DIVs have `position: relative`. The "auxiliary" linked DIVs (those with `position: absolute`) remain invisible to the user:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fca;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}

#div0 {
  margin-top: 80px;
  background: #ffd;
}

#divA,
#divB {
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
}

#div1 {
  background: #dff;
}

#div2 {
  background: #fdf;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#divA">To DIV1</a>
  <a href="#divB">To DIV2</a>
</nav>
<div id="div0">
  This is the top of DIV0
</div>
<div id="div1">
  <div id="divA"></div>
  This is the top of DIV1
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <div id="divB"></div>
  This is the top of DIV2
</div>
```

P.S.: This is the part that moves the page to the right spot despite your fixed navbar. If you want to achieve *animated* scrolling, you need Javascript/jQuery - no way around that... But there are plugins that can help you to do this kind of stuff, for example "Scrollmagic"

Comment: Thanks.This was easy and did not need to add any jquery or stuff.Your explanation was great aswell